# Permission denied when trying to edit .bashrc in a container

Tags: docker

Trying to run the command below:

```bash
docker container exec container-name echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> /root/.bashrc
```

but I'm getting the error below:

```
warning: An error occurred while redirecting file '/root/.bashrc'
open: Permission denied
```

I just created the container.
I can get into the container as root and execute the same command without error.
Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write in your host's root user `.bashrc`. It is good that you didn't run this as user root on host.

I think this is what you actually want:

```
docker container exec container-name sh -c 'echo . $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh >> /root/.bashrc'
```

Also you can use `/root` instead of `$HOME` since you already use that in the second part of the command.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!!
Can you try to clarify what is the `sh -c`? I mean, I know sh probably stands for shell and -c  maybe stands for command. What is not clear is if sh is an argument of exec command and if -c is an argument of sh. The syntax seems confusing to me.

Comment: if you want to run a command in the container, you want to send it as is and have the shell in the container interpret it. this is what `sh -c` does. without that, the command is interpreted before sending it to the container. This means that `$HOME` will be replaced with whatever `$HOME` you have on host and also the redirect `>>` is interpreted as being on the host. Also for this reason it is important to inclose the command after `sh -c` in single quotes, not double. I hope this clarifies. try to write some examples, if you  still don't get it let me know and I'll provide some

Comment: totally get it! many thanks for your attention!